# Using [midway] to label a curved path at its centre

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

I am trying to label two curved paths connecting two nodes with labels placed at their centres using the `node[midway]` option. This is something that should be very simple but I have not been able to come up with something that works. Here is my MWE with my question as two comments:

```
\documentclass[crop,border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node [draw,rectangle] (Start) {Start};
    \node [draw,rectangle] (Finish) [right=2cm] {Finish};
    \draw [->,out=90,in=90,looseness=0.75] (Start.north) to (Finish.north);
    % I want to label this path using [midway,below] as {forward}
    \draw [->,out=-90,in=-90,looseness=0.75] (Finish.south) to (Start.south);
    % I want to label this path using [midway,above] as {reverse}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

I also appreciate comments to improve code elegance or simplicity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must put the `node` direct after `to`

```
\documentclass[crop,border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [>=latex]
    \node [draw,rectangle] (Start) {Start};
    \node [draw,rectangle] (Finish) [right=2cm] {Finish};
    \draw [->,out=90,in=90,looseness=0.75] (Start.north) to node[above]{above}  (Finish.north);
    \draw [->,out=-90,in=-90,looseness=0.75] (Finish.south) to node[below]{below} (Start.south)
      ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that `[midway]` was not needed and that the syntax was simpler.

Comment: I am also a beginner^+ in tikz ;-) But I used this combination some days before

Comment: @chandra: I believe that `midway` (or `pos=0.5`) is the default so does not need to be specified. See [moving a label along the path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29713/4301) for more options for label placement.

Comment: @Peter Grill: Thank you for the explanation and link to a very helpful example.