# Add text and arrows in this tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a small scheme for the so called Goldbeter-Koshland loop. I'm almost done, but I have to include the text $E_1$ above the arrow that goes from P to P* and a small arrow that goes from the base of the text to the middle of the arrow. How can I do that? So far I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
from/.style={<-},
towards/.style={->},
protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
reaction/.style={}]
\node[protein] (p) at (-2,0) {$P$};
\node[protein] (ps) at (2,0) {$P^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] (p)
edge [from,bend right] (p) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I would like the figure to look something like:

```
   E_1
    |
   --->
P1      P2
  <--- 
    |
   E_2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a nodes with names and then draw the arrows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
from/.style={<-},
towards/.style={->},
protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
reaction/.style={}]
\node[protein] (p) at (-2,0) {$P$};
\node[protein] (ps) at (2,0) {$P^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node[below=20pt,name=e2] {$E_2$} (p)
edge [from,bend right] node[above=20pt,name=e1] {$E_1$} (p) ;
\draw[->] (e1) -- +(0pt,-25pt);
\draw[->] (e2) -- +(0pt,25pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can just add a node.

[image]

### Notes:

- You can adjust the position along the line by `pos=` option. I placed it at `0.5` which is the same as `midway`.  See [Moving a label along the path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29712/moving-a-label-along-the-path/) for more details.
- The `above` and `below` options are added so that the label is not on the line itself.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bend angle =60,inner sep=0pt, minimum size =10mm,very thick,
from/.style={<-},
towards/.style={->},
protein/.style={circle,draw=black,very thick},
reaction/.style={}]
\node[protein] (p) at (-2,0) {$P$};
\node[protein] (ps) at (2,0) {$P^*$}
edge [towards, bend left] node [pos=0.5, below] {$E_2$} (p) 
edge [from,   bend right] node [pos=0.5, above] {$E_1$} (p) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `auto` and `swap` you don't have to manually position the nodes at the arrows.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I am not familiar with those options. Using `auto` I get both nodes below the lines.  Using `auto, swap` I get both labels above the lines. Using `auto` for the first one and `auto, swap` does yield the desired result.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, it is. Normally one would issue `auto=[left|right]` to the outer scope and use only `swap` where it's needed. In this instance, I'd set `auto` and just use `\path[bend left, towards] (ps) edge node {$E_2$} (p) (p) edge node {$E_1$} (ps);` … no need to set any manual positions.