# Drawing lines in a plot and give them a label?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am on my first adventure in plotting with LaTeX. I managed to get my bar chart plotted. I have two groups of values for which I want to show the average. I intend to put a horizontal bar over the bar chart and let it indicate the average values.
Drawing is unfortunately not coupled to scaling or similar. In the moment I have to change something in the scaling/labeling everything will be out of its place.
Is there a best practice way of drawing lines (or arrows) that are corresponding to data values of the underlying chart?

Comment: could you add a MWE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you are having trouble using a `tikz` `\draw` within a `\pgfplot`'s `axis` environment. In this case you need to use the `axis cs` coordinate system as the dotted line in red illustrates:

[image]

### Notes:

- To add a label to this line you can use a `node` as part of the draw.
- The positioning of the label is covered at [Moving a label along the path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29712/moving-a-label-along-the-path).
- Thanks to Jake's answer at [Apply shift to (current axis.left of origin)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166882/apply-shift-to-current-axis-left-of-origin), the second MWE below should work without requiring specification of the minimum and maximum `x` values.  Only the `y` value needs to be specified in the `\VerticalPos` definition.

### Code: Specify both minimum and maximum x values

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {x*x};
    \draw [ultra thick, dotted, draw=red] 
        (axis cs: -6,12) -- (axis cs: 6,12)
        node[pos=0.5, above] {$y=12$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Automatically determine both minimum and maximum x values

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {x*x};
    
    \newcommand*{\VerticalPos}{12}% Desired vertical postion
    \coordinate (Left)  at ($(current axis.left of origin) +(axis direction cs: 0,\VerticalPos)$);
    \coordinate (Right) at ($(current axis.right of origin)+(axis direction cs: 0,\VerticalPos)$);
    
    \draw [ultra thick, dotted, draw=red] 
        (Left) -- (Right)
        node[pos=0.5, above] {$y=\VerticalPos$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```