# Apply shift to (current axis.left of origin)

Tags: pgfplots, calculations, coordinates

I was trying to improve the solution at [Drawing lines in a plot and give them a label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166871/drawing-lines-in-a-plot-and-give-them-a-label/166876#166876) by using Jake's answer at [How to access \xmin, \xmax, \ymin, \ymax from within PGFplots axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/how-to-access-xmin-xmax-ymin-ymax-from-within-pgfplots-axis-environment).
So, Jake's answer produces the brown dotted line (the x-axis)  with

```
(current axis.left of origin) -- (current axis.right of origin)
```

I thought a simple use of `tikz`'s `calc` library would allow me to adjust the vertical position of the horizontal line.   If I want a horizontal line at `y=12`, for example, I simply use

```
($(current axis.left of origin)+(axis cs: 0,12)$) -- ($(current axis.right of origin)+(axis cs: 0,12)$)
```

where I have applied a `+ (axis cs: 0,12)` and same for the other coordinate.

Well, that is great in theory, but doesn't work. Instead, it produces the dashed line in red (which is only half the desired line):

[image]

### Notes:

- Instead of doing coordinate calculations, I also tried applying `shift={(axis cs: 0,12)}` option but that had no effect on the output.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {x*x};
    
    \draw [ultra thick, dotted, draw=brown] 
        (current axis.left of origin) -- 
        (current axis.right of origin);
        
    \draw [ultra thick, dashed, draw=red] 
        ($(current axis.left of origin) +(axis cs: 0,12)$) -- 
        ($(current axis.right of origin)+(axis cs: 0,12)$);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you have to use `axis direction cs` in this case

Comment: @Jake: Yep that works. Please post that as an answer. Some info re: `axis cs` and `axis direction cs` would be useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know why but this works for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {x*x};

    \draw [ultra thick, dotted, draw=brown] 
        (current axis.left of origin) -- 
        (current axis.right of origin);

    \draw [ultra thick, draw=red] 
        ($(current axis.left of origin)-(axis cs:0,-12)$) -- 
        ($(current axis.right of origin)+(axis cs:0,12)$);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed. Very bizarre that a `+(0,12)` produces incorrect results, yet `-(0,-12)` produces the desired result. Perhaps a bug then?