# TikZ - Text centered between two right angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I can't seem to get the text centered between the two right angles along the path.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance = 2cm,
     state/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, align=center},
     >={latex},
     arrow text/.style={text width=1.8cm, rectangle, align=center, font={\tiny}, node distance=1cm},
     tmp/.style={coordinate}]

    % Main blocks
    \node [state]           (init)  {Initialization\\State};
    \node [state, right=of init]    (nonrt) {Non-Real-Time\\State};
    \node [state, right=of nonrt]   (rt)    {Real-Time\\State};
    \node [state, left=of init]     (off)   {Off\\State};
    
    % Tmporary nodes for routing arrows
    \node [tmp, below=of nonrt, node distance=.5cm] (tmpbelow) {};

    % Arrows
    \draw [->] (nonrt) -- node [arrow text, anchor=north] {text below} node [arrow text, anchor=south] {text above} (rt);
    \draw [->] ($ 0.5*(nonrt.south west)+0.5*(nonrt.south) $) |- ++(0cm,-.5cm) -| node [arrow text, midway, below] {text below} ($ 0.5*(init.south) + 0.5*(init.south east) $);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### MWE output

[image]

### Expected output

`text below` is centered along the arrow path between the two right angles.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pos=0.25` instead of `midway`.

[image: pos=0.25]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance = 2cm,
     state/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, align=center},
     >={latex},
     arrow text/.style={text width=1.8cm, rectangle, align=center, font={\tiny}, node distance=1cm},
     tmp/.style={coordinate}]

    % Main blocks
    \node [state]           (init)  {Initialization\\State};
    \node [state, right=of init]    (nonrt) {Non-Real-Time\\State};
    \node [state, right=of nonrt]   (rt)    {Real-Time\\State};
    \node [state, left=of init]     (off)   {Off\\State};
    
    % Tmporary nodes for routing arrows
    \node [tmp, below=of nonrt, node distance=.5cm] (tmpbelow) {};

    % Arrows
    \draw [->] (nonrt) -- node [arrow text, anchor=north] {text below} node [arrow text, anchor=south] {text above} (rt);
    \draw [->] ($ 0.5*(nonrt.south west)+0.5*(nonrt.south) $) |- ++(0cm,-.5cm) -| node [arrow text, pos=0.25, below] {text below} ($ 0.5*(init.south) + 0.5*(init.south east) $);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

When you use the `|-` option for a path, the point at the angle is considered at `midway` of the entire path. So the midway of the first line is at `pos=0.25`, as the midway of the second line is at `pos=0.75`.

Comment: +1 I did not know the behaviour of `midway` with `|-`. If one wants to avoid `pos=0.25`, one could use `near start`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29713/8650

Answer (score 0):

The answer by SebGlav is admittedly the easiest solution to your issue. However, for information purposes I will propose an alternate solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [node distance = 2cm,
        state/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, align=center},
        >={latex},
        arrow text/.style={text width=1.8cm, rectangle, align=center, font={\tiny}, node distance=1cm},
        tmp/.style={coordinate}]
        
        % Main blocks
        \node [state]           (init)  {Initialization\\State};
        \node [state, right=of init]    (nonrt) {Non-Real-Time\\State};
        \node [state, right=of nonrt]   (rt)    {Real-Time\\State};
        \node [state, left=of init]     (off)   {Off\\State};
        
        % Tmporary nodes for routing arrows
        \node [tmp, below=of nonrt, node distance=.5cm] (tmpbelow) {};
        
        % Arrows
        \draw [->] (nonrt) -- node [arrow text, anchor=north] {text below} node [arrow text, anchor=south] {text above} (rt);
        \coordinate (X) at ($(nonrt.210)+(0,-.5cm)$);
        \draw[->]  (nonrt.210) -- (X) -- (X -| init.320) node [arrow text, midway, below] {text below} -- ++(0,.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

I readily admit that using an additional `coordinate` to define the path is awkward, but I wanted to present you with an alternate way to define your angled arrow using the (name.number) syntax instead of the calc one. Also, for this type of diagram, I find the `(A |- B)` sytnax very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using standard packages (`stackengine`) ans `pstricks`:. The relevant frames are defined as `pstricks nodes`, and linked with the *ad hox* node connection;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\fboxsep} {1ex}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\noindent\framebox{\quad\Centerstack{Off \\State}\quad}\hfill\rnode{IS}{\framebox{\Centerstack{Initialization \\State}}}
\hfill\rnode{NRS}{\framebox{\Centerstack{Non-Real-Time \\State}}}\hfill\rnode{RTS}{\framebox{\Centerstack{Real-Time \\State}}}\par
\psset{arrowinset=0.1, linejoin=1}
\ncbar[angle=-90, arm=3ex, offsetA=-15pt, offsetB=-15pt]{->}{NRS}{IS}\naput{text below}
\ncline{->}{NRS}{RTS}\naput{text above}\nbput{text below}

\end{document}
```

[image]